# why cant my statement parse string to integer?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to parse a string to integer but I get incompatible types. My counter is for the amount of records that are in the file, the program can append to the file and read from it. now I want to sort it and write it back to file. How can I perform this task? variables that are not declared here are dclared globally.

```
public static void sort_addresses() throws IOException
{
 String tnumber;
 String tname;
 String tnrooms;
 int[] tmprooms;
 int[] tmprooms1;
 int j;
 for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
 {
    for(j = 1; j < (counter-1); j++)
    //while (street_name[counter] != null)
    {
        tmprooms = Integer.parseInt (number_rooms[counter]); 
        tmprooms1 = Integer.parseInt (number_rooms[counter+1]); 
        if (tmprooms[i] > tmprooms1[i+1])
        {
            tnumber = street_number[counter];
            tname =  street_name[counter];
            tnrooms = number_rooms[counter];
            street_number[counter] = street_number[counter +1];
            street_name[counter] = street_name[counter+1];
            number_rooms[counter] = number_rooms[counter+1];
            number_rooms[counter+1] = tnumber ;
            street_name[counter+1] = tname;
            number_rooms[counter+1] = tnrooms;
            System.out.println(street_number[i]+"\t"+street_name[i]
                +"\t"+number_rooms[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Declare:

```
  int[] tmprooms;
  int[] tmprooms1;
```

as

```
  int tmprooms;
  int tmprooms1;
```

[Integer#parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) returns an `int` , not an `int[]` .

Comment: Thanks guys, I forgot to mention 3 string arrays and I want to sort on number_rooms then write back to the file. Number_rooms declared Globally

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void sort_addresses() throws IOException
    {
     String tnumber;
     String tname;
     String tnrooms;
     int tmprooms;
     int tmprooms1;
     int j;
     for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
     {
        for(j = 1; j < (counter-1); j++)
        //while (street_name[counter] != null)
        {
            tmprooms = (Integer)number_rooms[counter]; 
            tmprooms1 = (Integer)number_rooms[counter+1]; 
            if (tmprooms[i] > tmprooms1[i+1])
            {
                tnumber = street_number[counter];
                tname =  street_name[counter];
                tnrooms = number_rooms[counter];
                street_number[counter] = street_number[counter +1];
                street_name[counter] = street_name[counter+1];
                number_rooms[counter] = number_rooms[counter+1];
                number_rooms[counter+1] = tnumber ;
                street_name[counter+1] = tname;
                number_rooms[counter+1] = tnrooms;
                System.out.println(street_number[i]+"\t"+street_name[i]
                    +"\t"+number_rooms[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: the response was inconvertable types---  tmprooms = (Integer)number_rooms[counter];

Comment: Hi shreyansh jogi, I now get number format excption at the tmprooms1 line.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt()` returns an `int` (which can be auto-boxed to an `Integer`), not an `int[]` array.

The variable `tmprooms` is of the type `int[]`, but `Integer.parseInt()` does not return an `int[]` array.

The following can be used to sort an `int[]` array:

```
Arrays.sort(int [])
```

Please see the following: [Arrays#sort(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29)

Comment: It returns an `int`; `Integer.valueOf` returns an `Integer`.

Comment: number_rooms has numbers in it and I want to sort it, how can I do that then please? There are 3 arrays in the file

Comment: thanks, I have 3 arrays in the same file. I think that sort will only sort on one

Comment: You may want to combine or merge the three int arrays and in this canse you may want to look at the following reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697255/combine-two-integer-arrays

Comment: blackpanther, The 3 arrays are stored as strings in a .txt file and I think that the best sort to do would be on number_rooms, thats why Im trying to sort it but I also want the rest of the arrays to be in sync

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- `tmprooms` and `tmprooms1` need to be `int`'s, not `int[]`'s.
- `j` needs to start from `0`.
- You need to use `j`, not `counter` for array accesses.
- The `System.out.println` where it is doesn't really print anything meaningful.
- `number_rooms[counter+1] = tnumber;` should be `street_number[counter+1] = tnumber;`
- This appears to be [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), just without stopping early (thus even less efficient than the already inefficient algorithm). There are far better algorithms out there, like the one used by `Arrays.sort` (see below).

Final code:

```
public static void sort_addresses()
{
  String snumber, sname, tnrooms;
  int tmprooms, tmprooms1;
  for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < counter - 1; j++)
     {
        tmprooms = Integer.parseInt(number_rooms[j]);
        tmprooms1 = Integer.parseInt(number_rooms[j + 1]);
        if (tmprooms > tmprooms1)
        {
           snumber = street_number[j];
           sname = street_name[j];
           tnrooms = number_rooms[j];
           street_number[j] = street_number[j + 1];
           street_name[j] = street_name[j + 1];
           number_rooms[j] = number_rooms[j + 1];
           street_number[j + 1] = snumber;
           street_name[j + 1] = sname;
           number_rooms[j + 1] = tnrooms;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/f6IMw6).

**A better way using objects:** (allowing you to use `Arrays.sort`)

```
static class Address
{
  int numberOfRooms;
  String streetNumber;
  String streetName;

  Address(String streetName, String streetNumber, int numberOfRooms)
  {
     this.numberOfRooms = numberOfRooms;
     this.streetName = streetName;
     this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
     return numberOfRooms + ":" + streetName + ":" + streetNumber;
  }

  // an alternative is to have the class "implements Comparable<Address>"
  //   and have a "public int compareTo(Address o)" function
  //   then you can just say "Arrays.sort(addresses)"
  public static Comparator<Address> numberOfRoomsComparator
     = new Comparator<Address>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Address o1, Address o2)
        {
          return Integer.valueOf(o1.numberOfRooms).compareTo(o2.numberOfRooms);
        }
     };
}

static Address[] addresses = {new Address("u1", "a1", 3),
                              new Address("u2", "a2", 1),
                              new Address("u3", "a3", 5),
                              new Address("u4", "a4", 4),
                              new Address("u5", "a5", 2)};

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Arrays.sort(addresses, Address.numberOfRoomsComparator);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(addresses));
}
```

Comment: Hi Dukeling, Why would there be an arror after the String in the statement: Address(String streetNumber, String streetName, int numberOfRooms)? It say it was wxpecting a )? Thanks again.

Comment: I've tried both sections and the first one is no giving number format exception at tmprooms1 = Integer.parseInt(number_rooms[j + 1]); I thought that porsing the string would overcome that but it has not. thanks again for your input so far. Im extremely new so the inefficiency of the code is why Dukeling

Comment: For the second piece of code - It shouldn't say that. That code should run as is. Feel free to put the code [somewhere](http://ideone.com) and I can take a look. A `NumberFormatException` means the string does not contain a parsable integer. The string should contain **only** an integer, nothing else. Try printing the string out and seeing what it looks like.

Comment: Cant seem to be able to paste the code here. but the error is at the first string of Address: -Address(String streetName, String streetNumber, int numberOfRooms)

Comment: Ive put it at your somewhere

Comment: You need to give me a link to it as well.

Comment: The `NumberFormatException` means the string does not contain a parsable integer. The string should contain only an integer, nothing else. I can't really help you, unless you provide a **complete** example (including the input of the program) that reproduces the problem - you can try printing the string out and seeing what it looks like, and which one gives you a problem, like [this](http://ideone.com/taiY2s).

Comment: Thanks Dukeling, The string array has only numbers so I wanted to sort the records by numbers, parsing number_rooms inro tmprooms and tmprooms1 as per the coding above.

Comment: the records in the file: 12b  Tetra Mews   2
45  Wellington Avenue   1
100  Camden Road   5
45  Kilburn High Street   3
34  College Row   1