# Merge two arrays and remove duplicates in Java

Tags: java, arrays, merge, duplicates

I am having trouble removing the duplicates from two arrays that have been merged into one. I have written the following code that merges the arrays, yet I'm not sure how to remove the duplicates from the final array. Assume the arrays are already sorted.

```
public static int[] merge(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
    int[] result = new int[list1.length + list2.length];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < (list1.length + list2.length); k++) {
        if (i >= list1.length) {
            result[k] = list2[j];
            j++;
        } 
        else if (j >= list2.length) {
            result[k] = list1[i];
            i++;
        } 
        else {
            if (list1[i] < list2[j]) {
                result[k] = list1[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                result[k] = list2[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: remove them before merging.

Comment: I don't know what the context of the problem is, or how critical the memory usage/speed of your program is, but you should start using collections. You could do all this in one or two lines.

Comment: Collections will wrap everything to an Integer, and if you are use a HashSet, it will create a zillion internal objects. If your arrays are of any significant size, or you are using this a lot, you should use the standard algorithm for doing this, which I have given below.

Comment: @rghome note this is quite an old question. The [tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff) in memory consumption (in a `Set<Integer>`, likely on the order of MB out of GB for sets sized in the millions) is that you save costs in cpu-consumption (~O(1) checks vs ~O(n)).  A `HashSet` is a non-starter for this question outside of performing dupe checks: The OP has sorted data, and `HashSet` is inherently unordered.

Comment: @Rouge It's not so much the memory space, but the expense of allocating it; i.e., all those Integers and other objects (depending on what classes you use), then the fact that they have to be garbage collected. There is no space-time trade-off. Using Collections will be slower _and_ use more memory. The trade-off is whether it is worth the programmer's time finding the best solution (hence the usefulness of this site!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, someone hated all the answers. Here's another attempt that combines two stackoverflow q's, [combining arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697255/combine-two-integer-arrays) and [removing dupes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967114/how-to-efficiently-remove-duplicates-from-an-array-without-using-set)

This one runs a good deal faster than my earlier attempt on two lists of  a million ints.

```
public int[] mergeArrays2(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
    int[] merged = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, merged, 0, arr1.length);
    System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, merged, arr1.length, arr2.length);

    Set<Integer> nodupes = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<merged.length;i++){
        nodupes.add(merged[i]);
    }

    int[] nodupesarray = new int[nodupes.size()];
    int i = 0;
    Iterator<Integer> it = nodupes.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        nodupesarray[i] = it.next();
        i++;
    }



    return nodupesarray;
}
```

console output:

```
INFO [main] (TestMergeArray.java:40) - creating two lists of a million ints
DEBUG [main] (TestMergeArray.java:41) - list 1 size : 1000000
DEBUG [main] (TestMergeArray.java:42) - list 2 size : 1000000
INFO [main] (TestMergeArray.java:56) - now merging
INFO [main] (TestMergeArray.java:59) - done, final list size is 864975
```

Comment: this answer does not take into account the fact that user is merging two sorted arrays and wants to maintain the sort.

Answer (score 3):

*this clearer lambda solution is slightly slower  because of the (un)boxing*
requires Java 8 or above

```
public static int[] mergedistinct( int[] array1, int[] array2 ) {
  Stream<Integer> s1 = IntStream.of( array1 ).boxed();
  Stream<Integer> s2 = IntStream.of( array2 ).boxed();
  return( Stream.concat( s1, s2 ).distinct().mapToInt( i -> i ).toArray() );
}
```

`[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 8]`

*if you need the array sorted:*

```
…
return( Stream.concat( s1, s2 ).distinct().sorted().mapToInt( i -> i ).toArray() );
```

Comment: There is `IntStream.concat()` also, `int[] foo = IntStream.concat(intStream1, intStream2).distinct().toArray();`,  Maybe this could avoid (un)boxing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique that iterates the arrays just once and does not use a hash to detect duplicates.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortedMerge {
    public static int[] merge(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int[] a;
        int[] b;
        List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        // b is longer than a
        if (array1.length > array2.length) {
            a = array2;
            b = array1;
        } else {
            a = array1;
            b = array2;
        }

        while (j < b.length) {
            int bb = b[j];

            if (i < a.length) {
                int aa = a[i];

                if (aa > bb) {
                    c.add(bb);
                    j++;
                } else {
                    c.add(aa);
                    i++;
                    if (aa == bb) {
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                c.add(bb);
                j++;
            }
        }
        // java 8 List<Integer> to int[]
        return c.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] array1 = new int[]{3, 5, 8, 11, 14};
        int[] array2 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 14, 15, 17};
        int[] c = merge(array1, array2);

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            System.out.format("%d,", c[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        // output> 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11,14,15,17,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your `merge` method and do the followings. I tested it. It works fine.

```java
int[] result = merge(count, count1);

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        set.add(result[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(set);
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ArrayLists? ArrayLists would make this very easy to do.

```
 //Consider n1 to be some global or instance variable.

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 public void Add(ArrayList<Integer> n2) {

     for(int i = 0; i < n2.size(); i++) {
         if(!n1.contains(i))
             n1.add(n2.get(i));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
package com.string.merge;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MergeArrayAndRemoveDuplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3};
        int[] b = {4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 4, 2};

        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < (a.length > b.length ? a.length : b.length); i++) {
            if (i < a.length) {
                int c = 0;
                while (c <= l.size()) {
                    if (l.contains(a[i]) == false) {
                        l.add(a[i]);
                    }
                    c++;
                }
            }
            if (i < b.length) {
                int c = 0;
                while (c <= l.size()) {
                    if (l.contains(b[i]) == false) {
                        l.add(b[i]);
                    }
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

```
o/p-[1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MergeListAndRemoveDuplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5};
        int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7};

        boolean flag = true;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                    flag = false;
                }
                if (i == j && !list.contains(b[j])) {
                    list.add(b[j]);
                }
            }
            if (flag == true) {
                list.add(a[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known algorithm for this. You should not use Sets or Lists and they will chew up memory and run slow for no benefit.

Here is a simple, standard and fairly optimal solution for merging sorted arrays. It assumes the incoming arrays are already sorted and contain unique integers.

```
public static int[] mergeSortedArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int[] result = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < array1.length) {
        while (j < array2.length && array2[j] < array1[i]) {
            result[k++] = array2[j++];
        }
        if (j < array2.length && array2[j] == array1[i]) {
            j++;
        }
        result[k++] = array1[i++];
    }
    while (j < array2.length) {
        result[k++] = array2[j++];
    }

    if (k != result.length) {
        result = Arrays.copyOf(result, k);
    }
    return result;
}
```